# Searching for an appropriate data structure in C++ to push into vector

Tags: c++

I want the following to be pushed in a vector, which data structure is suitable for the same:
I want to push:

```
(1, 10)
(2, 11)
(3, 12)
```

I know how to push into a vector an integer but i am not sure about the list that i have now. I am looking for a data structure which is memory efficient. I know i can use a vector as well as list in this case, but which one is memory efficient. If there is any other data structure which is memory efficient then please suggest.

Comment: `struct thing { int a, b; }`?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes:  Agreed.  Then you can declare `thing one; thing two;`

Comment: @James: No! No! Those Things should not be in this house! Make them go! They should not be here when your mother is not! Put them out! Put them out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some structure or `std::pair<int, int>`.

```
#include <utility> /* std::pair<T1,T2> */

...

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> vec;

vec.push_back(std::make_pair (1, 10));
vec.push_back(std::make_pair (2, 11));

for (auto iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter)
    std::cout << iter->first << " " << iter->second << std::endl;
```

Comment: The code above already shows you how to access them: first and second.

Comment: If this is C++03, there needs to be a space after the first closing `>` on the first line.  If it is C++11, you could also use `for (auto& pair : vec) std::cout << pair.first << " " << pair.second << std::endl;`

Answer (score 5):

How about `std::pair`?

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int> >
```